# How to integrate Selenium 2.21.0(previously Selenium RC) libraries with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, jar, selenium-webdriver

I want to add Selenum 2.21 libraries to Eclipse java project. I tried two methods.

**One through Command line:**

I have downloaded the Selenium 2.2(previously selenium RC) from their website for Java and unzipped them. When I write, java -jar (selenium-filename).jar, I am getting 'No main manifest attribute' error.

I know, the line mainclass has to be added in manifest file. There is no folder for the manifest in v2.21.

I also had Seleniumv1.03, which had the Manifest option. I added the line and a new line character, as mentioned in another post in someplace, but still I faced the issue.

**two through copy/paste of jar files under JRE system library of the project:**

This action is also not allowed. Cannot paste under JRE system library corresponding to the project.

*Can you please tell a step by step procedure, other than refering somewhere in Sun tutorial, where they have given about java cfe (jar name) (class name) (class name.class), for defining the entry point... I had tried that too, at present...*

For other reference, Java6 Update 32, I have downloaded for SDK and JRE. Firefox 12 and ie9, I am using. Eclipse Indigo IDE for Java Developers is been used.

Comment: Sorry, I am pretty much new to coding ...So, had problems with command line (and still I am with the above steps in question), but, with regard to eclipse, adding jars by copy, paste, was not an issue...Adding a folder by right clicking on the project and selecting, new folder and following the paste and build path, resolved the issue...! 

For wrt. command line, if someone can answer, it will be helpful ! Thanks

Comment: You should be downloading selenium-server-standalone.jar to start it from command line not the java bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have to do it download selinium jar file and save it in your project folder(Prefer if you have a lib floder)

Then right click on project in project explorer. You can find build path option. Then click on it and it will show you configure build path option. Then you can add your library in to the project. Just show the path for selinium jar file.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have done and it worked, and I have mentioned the same in previous comment of mine...! This is the correct solution...